# A simple question on inverse trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

> $$ \arctan \frac{2x+1}{ \sqrt{3}} + \arctan \frac{2y+1}{ \sqrt{3}} = ??$$

Isnt the formula $\arctan x + \arctan y = \arctan \frac{x+y}{1-xy}$ ?

My answer doesn't match with the textbook's

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry, the 2nd one was y. thanks edit made

Answer (score 3):

The formula you wrote is correct. Maybe calculation mistakes?

The answer is ugly.

$$\arctan\frac{\sqrt 3(x+y+1)}{-x-y-2xy+1}.$$

Comment: k mine is correct. my text got no sqrt 3 it says $\arctan \frac{x+y+1}{1-x-y-2xy}$

Comment: thanks for the quick answer

Comment: @chndn. If you textbook does got give you mathlove's answer, then your textbook is wrong !

Answer (score 0):

Add the following for practice in simplification and confirm text-book print error:

$ arctan  ( 1 + x + y +  \sqrt{1 - 2 x + x^2 - 2 y - 6 x y + y^2})/2 $

$ arctan ( 1 + x + y -  \sqrt{1 - 2 x + x^2 - 2 y - 6 x y + y^2})/2 $